# Merging lists of lists back together R

Tags: r, list, stack

I have a loop that generates lists of lists

so the result is something like

```
Result = list()
Result[[1]] = c(1,2,3,6,6,4)
Result[[2]] = c(32,123,432,12, 0, 0)
```

desired output:

```
Result = c(1,2,3,6,6,4,32,123,432,12, 0, 0)
```

I want to merge this back into one column to add to a dataframe?
How do I do this?

I tried:

```
do.call(rbind, Result)
```

but that just stacks them into a matrix
do I then have to melt that back with `tidyr`?

Comment: That is not a list of lists. It's a list of vectors. Please show the expected result.

Comment: added expected result

Comment: You don't want to `rbind` your list elements, you want to combine them: `do.call(c, Result)`

Answer (score 2):

Try simply this:

```
unlist(Result)
```